# In IDA Pro, is there a way to flag a function?

Tags: ida

I found a particularly important function using IDA Pro. However, the source is very large and I'm sure I'll lose track of it soon.

Is there a way to "flag" the function as important, color code it, or something similar?

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

1. edit the function and make it public
2. edit the function and color it
3. use markers (alt+m / ctrl+m)
4. give it a special prefix

I usually use 1 and 4

Answer (score 3):

1. Rename the function and give it a prefix, like "z_", and then you can find this function easily by sorting the function list by name.